# Handling optional boolean values

Tags: go

I'm failing to understand how I can work around the problem I'm  experiencing in my own application.

Imagine this example of a struct that models an incoming request and a function that puts the fields from that request into a database.

```
type NewBooleanRequest struct {
    RequiredString string `json:"requiredString"`
    OptionalBoolean bool `json:"maybeBoolean"`
}

func LogBooleanRequest(req NewBooleanRequest, db *sql.DB) {
    db.Exec("INSERT INTO log (booleanValue, stringValue) VALUES ($1, $2)", req.OptionalBoolean, req.RequiredString)
}
```

Now this obviously works fine if I know I will be given a value for all fields of my request model, but that's not a common requirement in reality.  How do people generally model "optional" semantics for `bool` values given that `bool` has a zero value that is valid in essentially all contexts?

Comment: A nullable boolean isn't really a boolean any more, it's a three-option enumeration at that point.

Comment: @Adrian: Sure, but that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @Flimzy it's specifically related to the question actually, but it's not an answer, which is why it's posted as a comment. And my point stands: it might be a good idea to rethink the model if you're looking at a nullable boolean.

Comment: @Adrian: No, not really. "bool" is a red-herring. This question really is about all optional/nullable types. A nullable bool is a bool in exactly the same way, and to exactly the same extent that a nullable string is a string.

Comment: It's not a red herring. It's most likely an issue arising from a bad design, and therefor an XY problem. I wouldn't say the same if it were not a bool, so the fact it's a bool is highly relevant.

Comment: @Adrian: No, nullable datatypes are not the result of bad design. They can be used in bad designs, but so can any other legitimate feature.

Comment: Not in general. I stand by my original assertion about nullable **bool** values, though.

Comment: @Adrian: The fact that you would not say the same if it weren't bool says a lot more about you than about the question.

Comment: This is really straightforward logic. The *entire purpose* of a boolean is that it has two possible values, true and false, allowing for *boolean logic* to be applied to it. A nullable boolean has three possible values, and boolean logic *cannot* be applied to it. Therefor a nullable boolean isn't really a boolean; it's a three-value enumeration with bizarre semantics.

Comment: @Adrian: Of course. And the entire purpose of a string is to store a sequence of zero or more characters. So I guess you never use a nil string pointer, either, since they can't be joined or concatenated, and have "weird semantics"? Your logic is just missing a vital piece. Null bools (and null strings, and null any other types) are perfectly valid, and convey valid information _apart from_ the data type or its normal valid range of values.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This question isn't specific to booleans, it's common for all NULLable types.  The simplest solution is to use a pointer (`*bool` in your example).  There are also Nullable values for common types provided by the [`sql`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql) package. [`sql.NullBool`](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullBool) would be the one you want in this case.

Comment: Sorry, typo -- I was going to ask if you think there is anything to be gained from introducing an optional wrapper type over just using pointers to implement a limited set of optional semantics

Comment: That depends mainly on how you'll be interacting with the value. Dealing with pointers can be cumbersome in some circumstances. Try one, and if you find it's painful, try the other, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the accepted answer, I found this interesting library https://github.com/guregu/null that can deal with nullable value pretty well. It's very useful to declare API request params without messing with `sql` library on the server routing (which is not so relevant).

For your case, you can write your request like:

```
type NewBooleanRequest struct {
    RequiredString string `json:"requiredString"`
    OptionalBoolean null.Bool `json:"maybeBoolean"`
}
request := NewBooleanRequest {
    RequiredString: "Your string",
    OptionalBoolean: null.BoolFrom(false)
}

if request.OptionalBoolean.Valid {
    fmt.Println(request.OptionalBoolean.Bool) // Print "false"
} else {
    fmt.Println("request.OptionalBoolean is NULL")
}
```